# "Display: block;" working inside <img> tag but not inside <style> tag

Tags: html, css

I have a html code where I don't want a white space between an image and the next row of my table.

Here is the code so far :

```html
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    @media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
      img {
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        /* If display:block; is here it does nothing */
      }
      table[class=tab] {
        width: 90%;
        font-size: 0px;
      }
      font[class=mainText] {
        font-size: 15px;
      }
      i[class=mainText] {
        font-size: 15px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#efefef">
  <table class="tab" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="600" bgcolor="#efefef">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
        <img src="header.png" alt="header" width="600" height="100%" /><!-- If i put style="display: block;" here it works -->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
        <p style="Margin: 0px 0px; color:#0098b6; font:19px sans-serif; line-height:24px;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;padding : 0px 20px 0px 20px;background-color:#f1e5dc;">
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
        <img src="camerone.png" alt="girl" width="600" height="100%" />
      </td>
    </tr>
```

If I add a style="display:block;" inside my two img tags, the white spaces disappear but if i try to put it inside my @media queries in img{} it does nothing. Why?

Comment: Replace `max-device-width` with `max-width`. Also you cannot use HTML comments inside CSS; use a CSS comment for that: `/* comment in CSS */`. Third, the `bgcolor` attribute has been deprecated 200 years ago. Fourth: Don't use tables for layout purposes (unless it's for email templates). We stopped doing that around 20 years ago.

Comment: Thanks for all the advices !
So i tried with max-width but it didn't change unfortunately.
2/ Thanks for the tips for the comments inside css !
3/ Ok i guess i should use background-color then?
4/ Yes it is for email templates

Comment: Your HTML is confusing with a </a>.... so what is the real HTML here?

Comment: Oh my bad I forgot to take those off, I will edit it right away !

Comment: Also a comment `<!-- If i put style="display: block;" here it works -->` not should be placed inside a tag. move that after of tag.

Comment: What is the rule you wrote to set display block? `table[class=tab] img { display: block; }` ???

Comment: No, I used `img { height: auto; width: 100%; display: block; }`

Comment: Why apply it to all images. Setting display block either way in your code worked. So my guess is you have other styles that override it?